# Delete recurring characters

Tags: c++, string, character, recurring

For a little something I was trying out in C++, I have accepted a string (say 'a tomato is red') and gotten rid of spaces ('atomatoisred').

Now how would I go about deleting recurring characters only, on condition that the first instance of that character gets to stay (so our example becomes,'atomisred')?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) might help with that.

Comment: @chris: no it won't. Read the description very carefully: _Removes all __consecutive__ duplicate elements from the range [first, last)._

Comment: @nightcracker, I forgot about that condition. Sorting doesn't work so well with the question :p

Comment: @chris: Not really. Read the contract.

Comment: Is this an interview question? If so there's quite a big discussion of this very question in *Programming Interviews Exposed: Secrets to Landing Your Next Job* by Mongan, Kindler and Giguère. I'm not going to plug it here, but I'm not going to plagiarize it either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) in conjunction with a set keeping track of the duplicate characters:

```
std::set<char> dupes;

str.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        str.begin(), str.end(),
        [&](char c) { return not dupes.insert(c).second; }),
    str.end());
```

This also uses the fact that the return value of `std::set::insert` is a pair whose second element is a `bool` indicating whether the insertion took place.

Comment: You use the ISO646-avoidance alternative names for logical operators?

Comment: @Steve Yes, consistently. Much more readable IMHO. We had some discussions about this on Programmers.SE, apparently now deleted.

Comment: I can't object, since I'm currently writing Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement it yourself (**without** `stl`), there are a number of ways.

1. Through sorting. This works if you don't care about the order of the chars. Sort your string first, then go through it, performing a very simple check on every element:

   ```
   if( currentElement == elemebtBeforeIt )
       deleteCurrentElement
   ```
2. Another way is to have an array dedicated to the unique characters (well, maybe not an array, but you'll get the idea). Go through your string, and for each charcter, check:

   ```
   foreach Element of the string:
       if( arrayOfUniqueElements contains currentElement ) 
           do nothing
       else
           put currentElement into the arrayOfUniquElements
   ```

   After this, you will have all unique elements in the dedicated array.